# Flex 3 - How to make a circular progress bar?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, progress-bar

I am a beginner in Flex. For my appln, I wanted to have the progress bar, but not the default that Flex Framework provides.

I wanted to have a circular loading "progressbar" that would move in circular fashion before completing one complete revolution to 100%.

Can I do that in Flex 3 ? If yes, how ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd better do this in Flash CS

Comment: If you're just starting with Flex, why are you using Flex 3? Why not Flex 4?

Answer (score 2):

Creating your own custom preloader is easy enough.  You just need to set the new preloader class in the 'preloader' property of the Application tag.

From there, your class (which should extend ProgressBar) can use simple Actiosncript to animation/draw or you can use a swf animation (done with Flash CS).  There are [several good examples of this](http://iamjosh.wordpress.com/2007/12/18/flex-custom-preloader/) on google.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? http://activeden.net/item/as3-circle-preloader-circular-progress-bar/88763

Use preloader or extend the progress bar component in Flex

You can have a circle component and a hidden progress bar in it. And for each progress bar event, you can paint a block on the circle.

Answer (score 0):

there is a property in Application "preloader". try setting your own SWC file to this property.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an already created component.

Here is a circular progress bar component created using Degrafa.
http://axelscript.com/wp-content/Examples/CircularProgress/CircularProgress.html

You can see the code at 
http://axelscript.com/wp-content/Examples/CircularProgress/srcview/index.html

The code is pretty simple , and as the component is shipped as a mxml component, integration should be very simple.

All you need is the degrafa.swc to be in the lib folder of your project for this to work.

Answer (score -2):

You could use [AS3GIF](http://code.google.com/p/as3gif/) and create your own "circular progress" animated GIF.

If, for example, your animated GIF has 20 frames, you can call the function `GIFPlayer.gotoAndStop(pFrame: int)` at each 5% step.

Comment: Why would you want to use a gif?! It's an archaic, poor quality image format that essentially tries to emulate what Flash does already.

Comment: @J_A_X: That's also what the HTML5 fanboy say about Flash. Animated GIF is a compact resource for animation and with as3gif it is also simple to use for beginners. Though I prefer PNG, but GIF's quality is sufficient in many cases.

Comment: It's 8 bit color, has poor transparency support, isn't interactive and it's more difficult to actually *create* a proper gif than using say, a swf.